# Automapper 5.0.2 - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: automapper

I've read all I could find online about this issue but nothing is helping.  Here is my code:

```cs
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserListViewModel>()
            .ForMember("RoleNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember("CostCentreNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember("RollupGroupNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.CostCentres, m => m.MapFrom(d => d.DetailCostCentres))
            ;
        });

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<CostCentre, CostCentreListViewModel>();

        });

var users = _repo.AllIncluding(u => u.Roles, u=>u.CostCentres).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList();
var  model = Mapper.Map<List<User>, List<UserListViewModel>>(users);
```

Mapper.Map is giving me the error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>       User -> UserListViewModel
>       Model.Models.User -> Model.ViewModels.UserListViewModel
>         Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   User -> UserListViewModel
>   Model.Models.User -> Model.ViewModels.UserListViewModel
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 45:
>      Line 46:             var users = _repo.AllIncluding(u => u.Roles, u=>u.CostCentres).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList();
>      Line 47:             var  model = Mapper.Map, List>(users);
>      Line 48:             return model;
>     Line 49:         }

Answer (score 5):

You can do only one `Mapper.Initialize` call:

```cs
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserListViewModel>()
            .ForMember("RoleNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember("CostCentreNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember("RollupGroupNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.CostCentres, m => m.MapFrom(d => d.DetailCostCentres));
            cfg.CreateMap<CostCentre, CostCentreListViewModel>();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually figured that one out but, it did not solve my issue.  I upgraded Automapper v 2 to v5 and it needed some code modifications to work.  in my case, it couldn't automatically handle the collections inside the object.  I had to add a line of code to specify that:

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me crazy all morning...We had multiple Mapper.Initialize instances and once we combined them into one, with profiles, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I actually figured that one out but, it did not solve my issue. I upgraded Automapper v 2 to v5 and it needed some code modifications to work. in my case, it couldn't automatically handle the collections inside the object. I had to add a line of code to specify that:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserListViewModel>()
            .ForMember("RoleNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember("CostCentreNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember("RollupGroupNames", c => c.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.CostCentres, m => m.MapFrom(d => d.DetailCostCentres));
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Role), typeof(RoleViewModel));
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof(CostCentre), typeof(CostCentreListViewModel));
        });
```